# I used AbpHub(SignalRHub) and after injecting the repository and writing the data, the data could not be committed to the database

Tags: asp.net-core, signals, signalr-hub, unit-of-work, abp

I used AbpHub(SignalRHub) and after injecting the repository and writing the data, the data could not be committed to the database.

I directly used the demo in abp-samples and was able to write data successfully.

But I made a new project myself, and after imitating it, I failed to write to the database (it did not prompt an error, but there was no data in the database).

I suspected that the unit of work was not in effect, so I manually enabled the unit of work. This time the data was written successfully, but I kept displaying an error: Volo.Abp.AbpException: Complete is called before!

```
        public async Task<SignalRTestDto> GetOrCreateAsync(string targetUserName)
        {
            var result = await _signalRTestRepository.FindAsync(s => s.Name == targetUserName);
            using(var uow = UnitOfWorkManager.Begin())
            {
                Logger.LogDebug("CurrentUnitOfWork.Id:{0}", CurrentUnitOfWork.Id);
                if (result == null)
                {
                    result = new SignalRTest(targetUserName);
                    await _signalRTestRepository.InsertAsync(result, true);
                    await CurrentUnitOfWork.CompleteAsync();
                }
            }
            return ObjectMapper.Map<SignalRTest, SignalRTestDto>(result);
        }
```

This is the project I tested:
https://github.com/zhangzw218/AbpSignalRDemo/tree/feature/2023070801_zzw_SignalR_Test

I compare the differences between the two Web, but can't find the problem.

Can someone take a look at this for me? I've integrated two projects into one solution:
..\AbpSignalRDemo\SignalRDemo2\SignalRDemo2.sln

Comment: `await CurrentUnitOfWork.CompleteAsync();` -> `await uow.CompleteAsync();`

Comment: Thank you, this modification can be used normally.
If app.UseUnitOfWork() is removed, then [UnitOfWork(true)] is also available.
If you do not remove app.UseUnitOfWork() and do not use [UnitOfWork(true)], you can still write data, but the error will not be rolled back, and the data is still written to the database.（This is a bit strange, I remember two days ago there should be this operation, remove [UnitOfWork(true)] after write data exception, but now can not reproduce.）

Comment: I don't really understand what you just said. So did my answer work?